# What is the difference between df.select() and df.agg()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe from which I want to extract Maximum value, Minimum value and Count the number of records in it.

The dataframe is:

```
scala> val df = spark.range(10000)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]
```

For getting the required values I am using `df.select()`, like this:

```
scala> df.select(min("id"), max("id"), count("id")).show
+-------+-------+---------+
|min(id)|max(id)|count(id)|
+-------+-------+---------+
|      0|   9999|    10000|
+-------+-------+---------+
```

Which gives me correct results, but when I tried `df.agg()` it also gave me same answer.

```
scala> df.agg(min("id"), max("id"), count("id")).show
+-------+-------+---------+
|min(id)|max(id)|count(id)|
+-------+-------+---------+
|      0|   9999|    10000|
+-------+-------+---------+
```

So, my question is what is the difference between `df.select()` and `df.agg()` if they provide the same results and which one should I use for better performance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select` is used to select required columns from a `dataframe` whereas `agg` is used to aggregate groups of `dataframe` applying some `functions` on that group.

In your case, `min`, `max` and `count` is performed on whole `dataset` and both `select` and `agg` are performing the same task i.e. transforming the aggregated `dataframe` to a new `dataframe`

Real difference will be evident when we have to perform the `aggregations` on groups of data. You can perform `agg` on grouped `dataframe` but cannot perform `select` on grouped `dataframe`. `select` query can be performed on whole `dataset` that a `pointer` is pointing.

If you checkout [grouped dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData.html), you can see definition as `"A set of methods for aggregations on a DataFrame, created by DataFrame.groupBy. The main method is the agg function, which has multiple variants. This class also contains convenience some first order statistics such as mean, sum for convenience."`

I hope the answer is clear

Comment: That is correct. But if `select` is only for selecting then how it is able to do aggregate operations like `max`, `min` and `count` like `agg` ?

Comment: select is not performing the aggregations. max, min and count functions are doing the aggregations. select is just selecting the mentioned columns and transforming to new dataframe.

Comment: I got that! But my question is how `select` is able to do an aggregation operation and which one is better ?

Comment: `select` is not doing the aggregation. `select` is just selecting the aggregated columns.

Comment: `select` should perform better. But I repeat again, `select` cannot be used in `grouped dataset` for aggregations.

Comment: Ok...so it means that `select` is first performing aggregation, and then it is selecting them. Did I got it correct ?

Comment: yes you got it correct. :) but I repeat again `select` is not performing aggragations.

Comment: Ok...got it! However, you were right about `select`. It is faster than `agg`. Any idea why ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147023/discussion-between-ramesh-maharjan-and-himanshuiiitian).

Comment: Thats because `agg` works by generating intermediate dataframes while processing whereas `select` doesn't. `select` just queries on whole aggregated dataset.

Comment: No!!! That's not correct. We can find sum using `select`. Both `df.select(sum("id"))` and `df.agg(sum("id"))` gave me same result.

Comment: min("id") and max("id") are also aggregations like sum("id") and they too gave you the same result. All I am saying is that agg is used with grouped data and select is used for whole dataset. I hope you get me this time

Comment: select and agg will always give you same result when you apply aggregation functions like max, min, sum, avg etc on whole dataset grouped as one.

Comment: Oh Ok! I got it, my mistake...I didn't noticed the `dataframe.groupBy` in the answer. You are correct.

Comment: Great to hear that @himanshuIIITian, and thanks for accepting. :) If you want you can upvote too. :)